# excel formula, Row Count with Where Condition

Tags: microsoft-excel

I am trying to get the count of rows where my column A = 'Stack' .

But Currently I just use `=ROW` but its not really specfic, as it gets count for all in column A.

Can anyone help me get the count for a specific word in a column?

Thanks..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is what COUNTIF() is for:

```
=COUNTIF(A:A,"Stack")
```

Answer (score 0):

```
=SUM(1*(A:A="Stack"))
```

Use control+shift+enter instead of enter, to enter this formula